# UserForm freezes after relaunching

Tags: excel, vba

My first UserForm is called DOORFORM. It has three buttons that open three different UserForms. The user will click one of the buttons and it will open up one of the corresponding UserForms.

In this case lets say he clicks on <kbd>ALUMDRBTN</kbd> and it opens up UserForm **ALUMFORM**.

After filling in the form the user clicks the <kbd>ADDBTN</kbd> and then closes **ALUMFORM**. **DOORFORM** automatically shows itself when **ALUMFORM** is closed (same with other two Forms).

The user then clicks <kbd>ALUMDRBTN</kbd> again and fills out the UserForm. This time when the user clicks the <kbd>ADDBTN</kbd> Excel freezes and the only way to close it is with Task Manager.

This is my problem. The same thing will happen if I use the other UserForms.

DOORFORM:

```
Private Sub ALUMDRBTN_Click()
Unload Me
ALUMFORM.Show    
End Sub

Private Sub HMDRBTN_Click()
Unload Me
HMFORM.Show
End Sub

Private Sub PRODRLIST_Click()
RunPython ("import  testconvertworking;testconvertworking.test_with_file()") 
End Sub

Private Sub WDDRBRN_Click()
Unload Me
WDFORM.Show
End Sub
```

ALUMFORM:

```
Private Sub ADDBTN_Click()
Dim DR_NUM As String
Dim DR_TYPE As String
Dim DR_HW As String
Dim DR_WIDTH As String
Dim DR_HEIGHT As String
Dim DR_THICKNESS As String
Dim DR_REMARKS As String
Dim DR_MODEL As String
Dim VISIONLT As String
Dim GLASS_LOUVER As String
Dim DR_FRAME As String
Dim DR_FINISH As String
Dim WIDTH_DES As String
Dim HEIGHT_DES As String
Dim VISIONLT_DES As String
Dim GLASS_LOUVER_DES As String
Dim PAIRORSINGLE As String
Dim Ret As Long

DR_NUM = DRNUMBOX.Value
DR_TYPE = DRTYPEBOX.Value
DR_HW = DRHWBOX.Value
DR_WIDTH = DRWIDTHBOX.Value
DR_HEIGHT = DRHEIGHTBOX.Value
DR_THICKNESS = DRTHICKNESSBOX.Value
DR_REMARKS = REMARKSBOX.Value
DR_MODEL = MODELBOX.Value
VISIONLT = VISIONLTBOX.Value
GLASS_LOUVER = GLLVBOX.Value
DR_FRAME = TUBEBOX.Value
DR_FINISH = FINISHBOX.Value

If PAIRBOX.Value = True Then PAIRORSINGLE = "PAIR OF "
If PAIRBOX.Value = False Then PAIRORSINGLE = ""

If DR_WIDTH = "306 mm / 1'-0""" Then WIDTH_DES = "(1'-0"")"
If DR_WIDTH = "381 mm / 1'-3""" Then WIDTH_DES = "(1'-3"")"
If DR_WIDTH = "457 mm / 1'-6""" Then WIDTH_DES = "(1'-6"")"
If DR_WIDTH = "533 mm / 1'-9""" Then WIDTH_DES = "(1'-9"")"
If DR_WIDTH = "610 mm / 2'-0""" Then WIDTH_DES = "(2'-0"")"


If DR_HEIGHT = "1829 mm / 6'-0""" Then HEIGHT_DES = "(6'-0"")"
If DR_HEIGHT = "1981 mm / 6'-6""" Then HEIGHT_DES = "(6'-6"")"
If DR_HEIGHT = "2032 mm / 6'-8""" Then HEIGHT_DES = "(6'-8"")"


If VISIONLT = "NONE" Then
    VISIONLT_DES = ""
Else
    VISIONLT_DES = ", " & VISIONLT
End If

If GLASS_LOUVER = "NONE" Then
    GLASS_LOUVER_DES = ""
Else
    GLASS_LOUVER_DES = ", " & GLASS_LOUVER
End If

With Sheets("DOORS").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
     .Offset(1).Value = DR_NUM
End With

With Sheets("DOORS").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1).Value = "TYPE " & DR_TYPE & ", HW# " & DR_HW
End With

With Sheets("DOORS").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1).Value = PAIRORSINGLE & WIDTH_DES & " x " & HEIGHT_DES & "   SPECIAL LITE " & DR_MODEL _
    & GLASS_LOUVER_DES & VISIONLT_DES & ", WITH " & DR_FRAME & " TUBE   FRAME, " & DR_FINISH
End With

With Sheets("DOORS").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1).Value = DR_REMARKS
End With

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim answer As Integer

 answer = MsgBox("DO YOU WANT TO DELETE THE LAST ROW?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "REMOVE LAST DOOR")

 If answer = vbYes Then
    Lastrow = Sheets("DOORS").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A" & Lastrow & ":D" & Lastrow).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
 Else
    'do nothing
 End If

 End Sub

 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 With DRWIDTHBOX
     .AddItem "306 mm / 1'-0"""
     .AddItem "381 mm / 1'-3"""
     .AddItem "457 mm / 1'-6"""
     .AddItem "533 mm / 1'-9"""
     .AddItem "610 mm / 2'-0"""
     .AddItem "686 mm / 2'-3"""
     .AddItem "711 mm / 2'-4"""

  End With

  End Sub

  Private Sub userform_terminate()

  DOORFORM.Show

  End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the code from the ADDBNT?

Comment: Hey Marco, The ADDBTN code is the first Sub in ALUMFORM.

Comment: There are no "**UserForm_Initialize**"? Also in VBA, `Dim A, B As String` does not make **A** a String type.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `DOORFORM.Show` statement in the _terminate event handler to confirm first of all whether the code ever *gets* that far :)

Comment: Thanks Guys, @PatricK, What code should i put in UserForm_Initialize, and should that be in both of my UserForms?Also for declaring my variables I should then enter it in as Dim A As String, Dim B As String, etc... Is this whats freezing my program?

Comment: @David Zemens I'll have to look up what a breakpoint is. Still learning :)

Comment: This will be your best friend: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx. learn all about how to debug your vba code. Great resource.

Comment: **Initialize** is the what runs before the useform is shown visually. Depending on different requirements, you may not need to Initialize a UserForm. I doubt the data type causes freezing but yes, that's how to define data types properly. Is that all your Subs? Oh, you concatenate strings with **&**, not **+**. Seems like you are from C#/C++.

Comment: @David Zemens I tried putting a breakpoint on DOORFORM.Show and I get the error "Run Time Error '424' object required". Does that mean one of my variable is not defined?

Comment: I would think that's the issue but what line raises the error?

Comment: @PatricK That is all my subs. Actually have not programmed in C#/C++, Im an intermediate/Beginner i would say when it comes to VBA. I formatted the data types correctly now i believe and changed + to &.

Comment: @DavidZemens I think its supposed to highlight the line that triggers the error but when I click OK on the error message it just goes back to the code with nothing highlighted except DOORFORM.Show which is highlighted in red for the breakpoint.

Comment: Sounds like Doorform is out of scope.

Comment: Actually, do you have an Initialize event in the Doorform module? If yes, can you include that code in your Q? That would be most likely.  You can step thru code line by line using f8 key and identify which line causes the error. There's also an option to break on all errors which you can set thru the menu in VBE options.

Comment: @David Zemens I was able to fix the error. The problem is definitely in the Sub UserForm_Terminate, that's what gets highlighted in yellow when pushing F8. I believe i found a way around it but I'm still curious on how to make it work. I moved Doorform.Show to my Addbtn Sub and it works no problem. Doorform is actually a UserForm and i plan on recoding it to have a UserForm_Initialize to populate my ComboBoxs and reset some of the fields. Right now i use rowsource to populate the comboboxs.

Comment: I might have an explanation let me think a minute...

Comment: There's gotta be something else going on, somewhere. You should be able to `.Show` a userform from within another form's `_Terminate` event but if I put together a simple test case, mine also "freezes" (I can escape it with Ctrl+Fn+Pause and then End runtime, but that's only slightly better than Ctrl+Alt+Del because at least that allows you to save & close without losing any work.  I observe this on the second attempt to "close" the form, the first attempt is no problem and works as-expected.

Comment: Perhaps use `DOORFORM.Hide` within DOORFORM and then `DOORFORM.Show` in others' `_Terminate`?

Answer (score 0):

ALUMFORM hasn't unloaded, and this is certainly causing some problems.

In the ALUMFORM `UserForm_Terminate` event, you are attempting `DOORFORM.Show` (you cannot display two `Modal` user forms at the same time.

You can probably resolve this by not using the form's event handlers to attempt to `Show` another Modally-displayed form.

Alternatively, display the forms with `Show vbModeless` and instead of Unloading them, do `Me.Hide`

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but Resetting the graphic card worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34863127)